# Javascript creating a link to another page with a JS function for that page

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a page that has multiple divs that can be toggled to be visible/invisible by the user.

Then I have another page that I want to link to something specific in the aforementioned page. How can I pass the javascript toggle code along with the link so that it displays the correct div, instead of just the default view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a url hash like site.com/page.html#div1

Then use javascript to parse the hash and decide wich div to show

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var selectedDiv = hash.split('#')[1];

//Then show selectedDiv
```

Comment: oh so thats how you do that. Thanks!